# Facebook sharing on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a javascript code to introduce a facebook share button on my website. When I click on this button, a pop-up window appears as usual, but the thumbnail selected is the facebook logo thumbnail. I wanted to show my logo instead of facebook logo. Can anyone help?

Here is my script.

```
<script>function fbs_click() {
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: try put your logo in a real image tag and the fb one into a css bg

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a og:image meta tag to your page.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite.com/thumb.jpg"/>
```

More info about [Facebook Meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).

Comment: I can't find the problem, metatag isn't working- and I am going nuts.

Comment: @FarigSadeque Maybe it's because Facebook has your page in its cache. Try Facebook Debugger (http://goo.gl/K9H1l). Paste your site address and click debug. Do you see the image you put in the metatag? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

ya, [Code of logo](http://developers.facebook.com/)  you can use this link for your reference, this will sure help.

Answer (score 1):

As Clement described, you should set an `og:image` metatag for your page, so all metadata crawlers can retrieve the image.

However, if you use the `FB.ui` method in the [FB JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/), you can specify the metadata directly:

```js
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://www.yoururl.com/',
    picture: 'http://www.yoururl.com/img/yourimg.png',
    name: 'Your Site',
    caption: '',
    description: ''
});
```

This share method is far more flexible than opening a new window directly to the old Facebook sharer.php.

The only reason you might not want to use this method is to avoid loading the extra JS file from FB.